# Tomcat hangs during webapp start up

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, refactoring

My *web project* was working perfectly, it includes: *spring3* and *hibernate3*. After renaming some fields in *eclipse* by the help of *eclipse refactoring*, *tomcat* could't start anymore. It hangs on these logs below:

```
    ......
    ......
    ......

2012-03-15 15:55:48,131 INFO [org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory] [newConnectionProvider] - <Initializing connection provider: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider>
2012-03-15 15:55:53,763 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <RDBMS: MySQL, version: 5.0.77>
2012-03-15 15:55:53,778 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <JDBC driver: MySQL-AB JDBC Driver, version: mysql-connector-java-5.1.15 ( Revision: ${bzr.revision-id} )>
2012-03-15 15:55:53,825 INFO [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] [<init>] - <Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect>
2012-03-15 15:55:53,825 INFO [org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionFactoryFactory] [buildTransactionFactory] - <Transaction strategy: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringTransactionFactory>
2012-03-15 15:55:53,841 INFO [org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionManagerLookupFactory] [getTransactionManagerLookup] - <No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional second-level cache is not recommended)>
2012-03-15 15:55:53,841 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled>
2012-03-15 15:55:53,841 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled>
2012-03-15 15:55:53,841 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <JDBC batch size: 15>
2012-03-15 15:55:53,841 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <JDBC batch updates for versioned data: disabled>
2012-03-15 15:55:53,856 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <Scrollable result sets: enabled>
2012-03-15 15:55:53,856 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): enabled>
2012-03-15 15:55:53,856 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <Connection release mode: auto>
2012-03-15 15:55:53,856 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <Maximum outer join fetch depth: 2>
2012-03-15 15:55:53,872 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <Default batch fetch size: 1>
2012-03-15 15:55:53,872 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <Generate SQL with comments: disabled>
2012-03-15 15:55:53,872 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled>
2012-03-15 15:55:53,872 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled>
2012-03-15 15:55:53,872 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [createQueryTranslatorFactory] - <Query translator: org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory>
2012-03-15 15:55:53,887 INFO [org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] [<init>] - <Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory>
2012-03-15 15:55:53,887 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <Query language substitutions: {}>
2012-03-15 15:55:53,887 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <JPA-QL strict compliance: disabled>
2012-03-15 15:55:53,887 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <Second-level cache: enabled>
2012-03-15 15:55:53,903 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <Query cache: disabled>
2012-03-15 15:55:53,903 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [createRegionFactory] - <Cache region factory : org.hibernate.cache.impl.NoCachingRegionFactory>
2012-03-15 15:55:53,903 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled>
2012-03-15 15:55:53,903 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <Structured second-level cache entries: disabled>
2012-03-15 15:55:53,919 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <Statistics: disabled>
2012-03-15 15:55:53,919 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled>
2012-03-15 15:55:53,919 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <Default entity-mode: pojo>
2012-03-15 15:55:53,919 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <Named query checking : enabled>
2012-03-15 15:55:54,090 INFO [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl] [<init>] - <building session factory>
2012-03-15 15:55:54,714 INFO [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory] [addInstance] - <Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured>
2012-03-15 15:55:54,933 INFO [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager] [afterPropertiesSet] - <Using DataSource [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@d99277] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager>
```

*Before refactoring the log continued like this below:*

```
2012-02-29 07:52:39,822 INFO [org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory] [afterPropertiesSet] - <Creating SAAJ 1.3 MessageFactory with SOAP 1.1 Protocol>
2012-02-29 07:52:39,853 INFO [org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller] [createJaxbContextFromContextPath] - <Creating JAXBContext with context path [aheeva.webService.oxm]>
2012-02-29 07:52:40,571 INFO [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping] [registerHandler] - <Mapped URL path [
.......
.......
.......
```

There are no errors anywhere strange!
Does Spring have any bugs? Why doesn't it tell if the scans or any other processes are faulty, I can't get it. Everything in Eclipse seems fine, nevertheless Tomcat hangs, this is really absurd!

Comment: So we're supposed to use our magical powers of ESP and look into your system to see what changed?  You should use your source control system to look at the differences between pre- and post-refactoring to figure out what happened.

Comment: If it was working before refactoring, it looks like Eclipse forgot to refactor something or on the other hand, it refactored something that it should not. Java classes do not use to be a problem (as far as you dont have compilation errors), but error can come from XML and properties files. Did Eclipse take in count other files as XML and not just Java ones? In any case, review configuration files.

Comment: all those logs are just INFO... so they are not pretty useful... you should look for ERROR, or SEVERE..

Comment: You can get crazy looking for the problem manually. Try to compare the current project with the version before repackaging using the control version tool so you can see what exactly has changed. Did you try with other Tomcat in order to be sure nothing happens with the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your problem take the following steps:

1. Take a look onto the script that *eclipse* generated when refactoring
   and compare the changes in the *Fields*.
2. Go down to the *xml* configuration files: *spring*, *hibernate*, *castor*,
   *web*,...etc and see if the compared *fields* are unchanged or
   overchanged and replace with the changes

If the above steps don't help perform these steps:

1. Download a fresh version of your project from your repository and
   make sure to run to see if everything is ok with it
2. Perform again the same changes one at a time from your change
   script, and run your project each time to see if it runs normally
3. At the point where your project stops working, you will know on which
   concrete *field*-change *tomcat* started to hang, and get deep into it to
   tackle

Comment: Did you perform all the steps I wrote above?

Answer (score 2):

This is a really weird issue, I had to spend hours debugging this... some steps you can try:

- Delete the project and import again
- Create a new *workspace*
- Revert to an older version of the project and see
- Manually delete all the build/bin/target/log/classes folders (*this worked for me*)
- Restart Eclipse

**Update**

Cleaning up the project directory solves this issue. Either do CVS/SVN Clean or manually delete all the class/build files.

**Update 2**

I found one more issue. I have a cron schedule

`@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/1 * * * ?")` works fine

`@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/0 * * * ?")` fails!!!

Answer (score 1):

OK, if you have this problem in eclipse you need to use eclipse IDE there's no escape.
I advise you to get going with the following as start-ups for your spring web-apps:

1. Try Spring *ReadMe* s and *HowTo* s on their [website](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/)
2. Use spring [forum](http://forum.springsource.org/forumdisplay.php)s to post questions.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. Well, ***Spring*** needs the ***autowired*** fields to have the same name as their classes and ***spring-config.xml*** file's beans' ids. so if any change must be done for any of these three names:

1. Class name
2. Field name
3. Bean id name

The other two must be changed as well, so that always the three objects have the same name.
That's how ***Spring*** works ;-)

Comment: There are ways to persuade autowiring to work in other ways, apparently. (I've no deep experience though; I manually wire where I can because it acts as documentation of my application configuration.)

Comment: @DonalFellows But don't you follow the above rule?